# Wrong POST body JSON serialization when using postForEntity in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I'm trying to send an instance of the object `EGiftCreationRequest` as JSON via POST body in Spring:

```
    final BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(100.00);
    final String configurationId = "test_configuration_id";
    final String referenceNumber = "12345";

    EGiftCreationRequest giftCreationRequest = new EGiftCreationRequest() {{
        giftAmount(amount);
        productConfigurationId(configurationId);
        retrievalReferenceNumber(referenceNumber);
    }};

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<EGiftCreationRequest> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<EGiftCreationRequest>(giftCreationRequest, headers);

    ResponseEntity<EGift> entity = new TestRestTemplate().postForEntity(
            "http://localhost:" + this.port + "/eGiftProcessing/v1/generateEGift",
            httpEntity,
            EGift.class
    );
```

However, for some reason the object is being serialized into the following String:

```
{"headerParams":{}}
```

Obviously this has nothing to do with my `EGiftCreationRequest`, which is actually:

```
public class EGiftCreationRequest extends RequestBase<EGiftCreationRequest> {
    private BigDecimal giftAmount;
    private String productConfigurationId;
    private String retrievalReferenceNumber;

    public BigDecimal giftAmount() {
        return this.giftAmount;
    }

    public String productConfigurationId() {
        return this.productConfigurationId;
    }

    public String retrievalReferenceNumber() {
        return this.retrievalReferenceNumber;
    }

    public EGiftCreationRequest giftAmount(final BigDecimal giftAmount) {
        this.giftAmount = giftAmount;
        return this;
    }

    public EGiftCreationRequest productConfigurationId(final String productConfigurationId) {
        this.productConfigurationId = productConfigurationId;
        return this;
    }

    public EGiftCreationRequest retrievalReferenceNumber(final String retrievalReferenceNumber) {
        this.retrievalReferenceNumber = retrievalReferenceNumber;
        return this;
    }
}
```

What can possibly be going on?

Comment: From the information given, unless someone has seen the exact same behavior, it'll be hard to give an answer. What can help is debug statements, full code for controller, and very basic - just debug the code in your IDE.

Comment: Do you have the jackson json jar in your classpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a misconfigured Jackson mapper. By default, Jackson is looking for accessors named in JavaBeans fashion (get*(), set*()) to retrieve and set values. Since the model uses a different naming convention (the field names themselves), Jackson fails to serialize the object.

The following mapper configuration makes everything work correctly:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.GETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.SETTER, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);
    mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.CREATOR, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.NONE);

    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate = new TestRestTemplate();
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
    messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(mapper));

    testRestTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
```